# Customized daily calendar view in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-calendar

[image]

I want to create daily calender view like shown in image. It must have  Functionality to  add, modify, reschedule events dynamically. It should not be 24 hr basis calendar (hours be any number between 1 to 24 ) and time span could be of any minutes like 5 min up to 1 hr (this also decided dynamically). Events rescheduling should be possible with Drag and Drop option. 
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please note that "I can haz teh code?" questions are not encouraged on SO. Please show us what you have done, what problems you have encountered or at least narrow down the scope of your problem.

Comment: Download the source code from here.. http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/10/custom-calendar-in-android.html and then try to change the font and other events from within the source code. If you then face any issues, post your query here.. no one is going to help you with logic and code it for you.